# Centering a specific div over a point on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a game where the canvas is used to animate most of the game, but the timer for the game is not rendered on the canvas, and is instead in a separate div. I have been trying to find a way to center the timer around the same point that the squares on the canvas (all shown in the snippet below) are centered around that is also reactive and will work on any platform/screen size. Everything I've tried so far either works for mobile and not browser, or vice versa. Any ideas how to center the timer on the same point as the canvas objects that will work with any screen size?

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
async function timer(){
  timeleft = 15;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "0";
    gameOverText.innerHTML = "Your Score: " + score;
    gameOverModal.style.display = "block";
    DoExampleLoginWithCustomID()
    console.log(score);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}

function initTimer(top, left){
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  timer.innerHTML = "15";
  timer.style.textAlign = "center";
  timer.style.position = "absolute";
  timer.style.top = top;
  timer.style.left = left;
  timer.style.transform = "translate(-50%, 0%)";
  timer.style.fontSize = "4vw";
  timer.style.letterSpacing = "0.1em";
  timer.style.webkitTextStrokeWidth = "0px";
  timer.style.webkitTextFillColor = "transparent";
  //timer.style.webkitTextStrokeColor = "white";
  timer.style.textShadow = "2px 2px " + textColor + ", 4px 4px " + shadowColor + "";
}

class rectButton {
  constructor(padx, pady, height, width, r, g, b, target) {
    this.padx = padx;
    this.pady = pady;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.fillColor = "rgb(" + [r,g,b].join() + ")";
    this.strokeColor = "rgb(" + [r*(0.5),g*(0.5),b*(0.5)].join() + ")";
    this.target = target;
  }

  setChosen(percent){
    if (first = true){
      this.r = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.r) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.g = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.g) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.b = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.b) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.fillColor = "rgb(" + [this.r,this.g,this.b].join() + ")";
    }
  }
}

//Initialize Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("game");
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("gameCont");
canvas[0].width = parent[0].offsetWidth;
canvas[0].height = document.body.clientHeight;

let gameActive = true;
let first = true;
let correct = false;
let custId = getRandomInt(1000000000000000000).toString();
let backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [getRandomInt(255),getRandomInt(255),getRandomInt(255)].join() + ")";
let r = getRandomInt(255);
let g = getRandomInt(255);
let b = getRandomInt(255);
let populatelb = true;
let score = 0;
let timeleft = 15;
let exes  = [];
let textColor = "rgb(" + [r,g,b].join() + ")";
let shadowColor = "rgb(" + [r*(0.8),g*(0.8),b*(0.8)].join() + ")";
let rects = [];
let left = "";
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.width = document.body.clientWidth;
context.height = document.body.clientHeight;

if(context.width > context.height){
  var basis = context.height;

} else {
  var basis = context.width;
}

let midx = context.width/2-(basis/8);
let midy = context.height/2-(context.height/8)-50;
let targets = []

let tmp = getRandomInt(4);
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  if(tmp == i){
    targets[i] = true;
  } else{
    targets[i] = false;
  }

}
rects[0] = new rectButton((midx-(basis/6)), (midy-(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[0]);
rects[1] = new rectButton((midx+(basis/6)), (midy-(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[1]);
rects[2] = new rectButton((midx+(basis/6)), (midy+(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[2]);
rects[3] = new rectButton((midx-(basis/6)), (midy+(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[3]);

//timer size and location
var head = document.getElementById("header");
let toptmp = (((head.offsetHeight + parent[0].offsetHeight)/2)) + "px";

left = "50vw";


//Main game loop logic
const loop = function () {

  // Creates the backdrop for each frame
  context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height); // x, y, width, height

  for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++){
    context.beginPath();
    if ((rects[i].target == true) && (first == true)){
      rects[i].setChosen(0.8);
      first = false;
    }
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = rects[i].fillColor;
    context.strokeStyle = rects[i].strokeColor;
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.rect(rects[i].padx, rects[i].pady, rects[i].width, rects[i].height);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};

initTimer(toptmp, left);
timer()
// Start animation loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900i&display=swap');

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
                        1px 1px #4EB1D9,
                        2px 2px #000000;
}

footer {
  position: static;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  /*position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;   */         /* Footer height */
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  block-size: 100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

img {
  float: center;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 25vw;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

button {
  float: center;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#gameCont{
  display: flex;
  float: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.game{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff1f8f;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
                        2px 2px #4EB1D9,
                        4px 4px #000000;
}

.header button {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header v.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  width: 75%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  text-align: center;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*LeaderBoard Table Defs */
.tableFixHeadLB {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 60vh;
}
.tableFixHeadLB thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/*Table Defs */
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 30vh;
}
.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed ;
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 1vh 1vh;
  align-items: center;
}
th {
  background: #eee;
}
.tableFixHead,
.tableFixHead td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHead th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB,
.tableFixHeadLB td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Next</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"/>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header" id="header">
    <a href="#default" class="logo">Next</a>
    <div class="header-right">

    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="h1"></h1>
  <div class="gameCont">
    <h1 id="timer"></h1>
    <canvas class="game"></canvas>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why put the timer in a separate div??  That mix of div and canvas is going complicate your game a lot ... maybe you should look into a proper game engine: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: `what is the best way...` will always lead to an opinion-based answer and as such will be out of scope for SO. However this is just a bad choice of words as you have an actual valid question. Consider editing the "bad" phrasing.

Comment: Have you considered flexbox or grid? also it would be easier to use `classList` to add/remove a CSS class instead of setting dozens of properties through JS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your issue is caused by a few typos. I will post them as an aswer because comments are to short to lead you through it. Please consider to voluntarily remove the question if this solves the issue for you as the issue as said is soley cause by typos.

1. In CSS line 75 you used `#gameCont` as selctor. However no element with this ID exist. You have an element `<div class="gameCont">` in HTMl line 20. You need to fix the selctor to `.gameCont`
2. You try to position the timer absolute but you have no parent with `position: relative` and as such the next relative parent will be the `<body>` element. You have to add: `.gameCont { position: relative; }` to your CSS.
3. In JS line 26 and 27 you used `element.style.top = top;` and `element.style.left = left;` which either are incorrect values or varaibles you never declared. you have to change bot values to `"50%"`
4. Then in JS line 28 you declared `element.style.transform = "translate(-50%, 0);" which has to be` translate(-50%, -50%)` instead.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
async function timer(){
  timeleft = 15;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "0";
    gameOverText.innerHTML = "Your Score: " + score;
    gameOverModal.style.display = "block";
    DoExampleLoginWithCustomID()
    console.log(score);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}

function initTimer(top, left){
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  timer.innerHTML = "15";
  timer.style.textAlign = "center";
  timer.style.position = "absolute";
  timer.style.top = "50%";
  timer.style.left = "50%";
  timer.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  timer.style.fontSize = "4vw";
  timer.style.letterSpacing = "0.1em";
  timer.style.webkitTextStrokeWidth = "0px";
  timer.style.webkitTextFillColor = "transparent";
  //timer.style.webkitTextStrokeColor = "white";
  timer.style.textShadow = "2px 2px " + textColor + ", 4px 4px " + shadowColor + "";
}

class rectButton {
  constructor(padx, pady, height, width, r, g, b, target) {
    this.padx = padx;
    this.pady = pady;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.fillColor = "rgb(" + [r,g,b].join() + ")";
    this.strokeColor = "rgb(" + [r*(0.5),g*(0.5),b*(0.5)].join() + ")";
    this.target = target;
  }

  setChosen(percent){
    if (first = true){
      this.r = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.r) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.g = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.g) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.b = Math.floor(parseFloat(this.b) * parseFloat(percent));
      this.fillColor = "rgb(" + [this.r,this.g,this.b].join() + ")";
    }
  }
}

//Initialize Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("game");
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("gameCont");
canvas[0].width = parent[0].offsetWidth;
canvas[0].height = document.body.clientHeight;

let gameActive = true;
let first = true;
let correct = false;
let custId = getRandomInt(1000000000000000000).toString();
let backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [getRandomInt(255),getRandomInt(255),getRandomInt(255)].join() + ")";
let r = getRandomInt(255);
let g = getRandomInt(255);
let b = getRandomInt(255);
let populatelb = true;
let score = 0;
let timeleft = 15;
let exes  = [];
let textColor = "rgb(" + [r,g,b].join() + ")";
let shadowColor = "rgb(" + [r*(0.8),g*(0.8),b*(0.8)].join() + ")";
let rects = [];
let left = "";
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.width = document.body.clientWidth;
context.height = document.body.clientHeight;

if(context.width > context.height){
  var basis = context.height;

} else {
  var basis = context.width;
}

let midx = context.width/2-(basis/8);
let midy = context.height/2-(context.height/8)-50;
let targets = []

let tmp = getRandomInt(4);
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  if(tmp == i){
    targets[i] = true;
  } else{
    targets[i] = false;
  }

}
rects[0] = new rectButton((midx-(basis/6)), (midy-(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[0]);
rects[1] = new rectButton((midx+(basis/6)), (midy-(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[1]);
rects[2] = new rectButton((midx+(basis/6)), (midy+(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[2]);
rects[3] = new rectButton((midx-(basis/6)), (midy+(basis/6)), basis/4, basis/4, r, g, b, targets[3]);

//timer size and location
var head = document.getElementById("header");
let toptmp = (((head.offsetHeight + parent[0].offsetHeight)/2)) + "px";

left = "50vw";


//Main game loop logic
const loop = function () {

  // Creates the backdrop for each frame
  context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height); // x, y, width, height

  for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++){
    context.beginPath();
    if ((rects[i].target == true) && (first == true)){
      rects[i].setChosen(0.8);
      first = false;
    }
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = rects[i].fillColor;
    context.strokeStyle = rects[i].strokeColor;
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.rect(rects[i].padx, rects[i].pady, rects[i].width, rects[i].height);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};

initTimer(toptmp, left);
timer()
// Start animation loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900i&display=swap');

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
                        1px 1px #4EB1D9,
                        2px 2px #000000;
}

footer {
  position: static;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  /*position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;   */         /* Footer height */
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  block-size: 100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

img {
  float: center;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 25vw;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

button {
  float: center;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.gameCont{
  display: flex;
  float: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.game{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff1f8f;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
                        2px 2px #4EB1D9,
                        4px 4px #000000;
}

.header button {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header v.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  width: 75%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  text-align: center;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*LeaderBoard Table Defs */
.tableFixHeadLB {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 60vh;
}
.tableFixHeadLB thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/*Table Defs */
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 30vh;
}
.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed ;
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 1vh 1vh;
  align-items: center;
}
th {
  background: #eee;
}
.tableFixHead,
.tableFixHead td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHead th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB,
.tableFixHeadLB td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Next</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"/>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header" id="header">
    <a href="#default" class="logo">Next</a>
    <div class="header-right">

    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="h1"></h1>
  <div class="gameCont">
    <h1 id="timer"></h1>
    <canvas class="game"></canvas>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```